# What's the most efficient way to format the following string?

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I have a very simple question, and I shouldn't be hung up on this, but I am. Haha!

I have a string that I receive in the following format(s):

123

123456-D53

123455-4D

234234-4

123415

The desired output, post formatting, is:

123-455-444

123-455-55

123-455-5

or

123-455

The format is ultimately dependent upon the total number of characters in the original string..

I have several ideas of how to do this, but I keep thing there's a better way than string.Replace and concatenate...

Thanks for the suggestions..

Ian

Comment: Are you sure that efficiency is the most important metric here and not for example readability? Have you profiled to see that this is the bottleneck in your program?

Comment: No on both accounts. In-fact, I'm certain that it's not a bottleneck and that efficiency is not the most important metric. I'm just curious and have been thinking about it all day. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this does not merely rely upon the inputs always being numeric? If so, I'm thinking of something like this

```
private string ApplyCustomFormat(string input)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input.Replace("-", ""));

    int index = 3;
    while (index < builder.Length)
    {
        builder.Insert(index, "-");
        index += 4;
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is similar to my implementation.. I'm just caught up on the "is this the most efficient way to do this?" question..

Comment: @Ian P -- "most efficient" is less important than "efficient enough". See the first comment. I would be tempted to write "less efficient" code that uses an IEnumerable chunker (method or Regex) and String.Join ;-)

Comment: Picked this one as the answer, as it worked first per the spec I describe. Although, the other posters updated their code to work as required as well. All are worthy of green checkmarks, but I can only give one :)

Answer (score 4):

Tanascius is right but I cant comment or upvote due to my lack of rep but if you want additional info on the string.format Ive found this helpful.
http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Comment: I should have let you know that I deleted my answer :-). The OP changed the question and it no longer applies. Besides, sixlettervariable pointed out that it actually does not answer the original question too.

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT: See history for old versions.*
You could use [**char.IsDigit()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58.aspx) for finding digits, only.

```
var output = new StringBuilder();
var digitCount = 0;

foreach( var c in input )
{
  if( char.IsDigit( c ) )
  {
    output.Append( c );
    digitCount++;
    if( digitCount % 3 == 0 )
    {
      output.Append( "-" );
    }
  }
}

// Remove possible last -
return output.ToString().TrimEnd('-');
```

This code should fill from left to right (now I got it, first read, then code) ...
Sorry, I still can't test this right now.

Comment: I am about to clarify my original post, the string can be alphanumeric, not just numeric.

Comment: I think this fills the numbers in the wrong direction. He wants it Left-Justified, so to speak.

Comment: @Ian: I use char.IsDigit, now. @sixlettervariables: you are right, that makes it a lot more difficult.

Comment: @Ian: My solution removes letters, now ... hope you wanted this, because it is not clear from your question (all outputs have numbers, only)

Comment: I'm not on newest .Net so this may have been changed, but shouldn't `== "-"` be replaced with `== '-'`?

Comment: instead of your last if you could simply do
output = output.TrimEnd('-');

Comment: @Brian: Thanks, that's the simple stuff I didn't find without a compiler :/

Comment: @Rune FS/tanascius: Since remove doesn't work on .Net 2.0, I'll assume it doesn't work on newer .Net.  I replaced it with a return using Rune FS's change.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that uses a combination of regular expressions and LINQ to extract groups of three letters at a time and then joins them together again. Note: it assumes that the input has already been validated. The validation can also be done with a regular expression.

```
string s = "123456-D53";
string[] groups = Regex.Matches(s, @"\w{1,3}")
                       .Cast<Match>()
                       .Select(match => match.Value)
                       .ToArray();
string result = string.Join("-", groups);
```

Result:

```
123-456-D53
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the fastest, but easy on the eyes (*ed: to read*):

```
string Normalize(string value)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return value;

    int appended = 0;
    var builder = new StringBuilder(value.Length + value.Length/3);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < value.Length; ++ii)
    {
        if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(value[ii]))
        {
            builder.Append(value[ii]);
            if ((++appended % 3) == 0) builder.Append('-');
        }
    }

    return builder.ToString().TrimEnd('-');
}
```

Uses a guess to pre-allocate the `StringBuilder`'s length. This will accept any Alphanumeric input with any amount of junk being added by the user, including excess whitespace.

Comment: Haha, we must have different types of eyes :p

Comment: You should be checking for `(ii + 1) % 3 == 0`.

Comment: @0xA3: good catch. @pst: if I'm coming back through to read this, it'll be obvious what's going on. No obfuscation ;)

Comment: You updated the code, but it is still wrong ;-) So either check for `((builder.Length+ 1) % 4) == 0` or for `((ii + 1) % 3 == 0)`.